# How to change the UI5 Library Source path in SAP Fiori Elements extention App?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to change the UI5 library source path in a fiori elements extension app(Analytical List Page).

In the standalone UI5 apps we can change the Source path in the index.html file

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        ***src=https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js***
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize_plus"
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"Firefly_no_upgrade": ""}'>
    </script>
```

As there is no index.html or similar files in the Fiori elements app(Analytical List Page), how do i change the ui5 library source path.

Comment: Where and how the application is hosted? Do you load the app via the lauchpad in an ABAP system?

Comment: Yes, we hosted the application in the fiori launchpad of ABAP System. Right now the app is taking the ui5 library from the ABAP system, but we need the app to access the library from https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js. Where should i change the ui5 library source path?

Comment: usually it's just something like `src="/resources/sap-ui-core.js"`, but if you configure launchpad properly to use semantic objects and components, it doesn't use the index file at all

Comment: In a UI5 Custom application we can change this in index.html as you said. But in Analytical List Page there is no such file. But there should be a way to tell the app to use the desired UI5 Library. Unfortunately i can't find it. any help is appreciated.

Comment: this is impossible; A  extension is a "extension" and lives in the same context as the launchpad itself. You can't change this. Upgrade the launchpad, or build your own standalone app by copying the entire root application and add index.html... etc.

But again you can't run it in a  launchpad